# Pattern for Single Connection in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, httpconnection

We would like to use single instance of `Http Connection` to communicate to server as it's guaranteed to communicate to one end http endpoint

Ex:

```
MyConnection.GetRoute<ABC>.DoStuff()   --https://user.site.com/abc/
MyConnection.GetRoute<XYZ>.DoStuff()   --https://user.site.com/xyz/
```

From the design patterns, Singleton seems to make perfect case

```
public class MyConnectionHelper
{
   private static MyConnection instance;

   private MyConnectionHelper() {}

   public static MyConnectionHelper Instance
   {
       get{
         if(instance == null){
            instance = new MyConnection();
         }
         return instance;
       }
   }
}
```

But we need some credentials to make connection and proxy information to be used if required, these properties should be exposed

```
public class MyConnectionHelper
{
   public static string authKey;
   public static string proxyUrl;
   private static MyConnection instance;

   private MyConnectionHelper() {}

   public static MyConnectionHelper Instance
   {
       get{
         if(instance == null) {
            instance = new MyConnection(proxyUrl, authKey);
         }
         return instance;
       }
   }
}
```

Is there any better design pattern suits for this use case and better way to expose `required/optional` parameters that can be provided before creating the connection and reuse it through out the cycle.

Comment: Have you considered using `HttpClient`?

Comment: You forgot some spaces there `private static MyConnectioninstance;` (first class) and there `public static MyConnectionHelperInstance` (second class). Not enough characters to edit

Comment: Have you considered using `Lazy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the code below. When you set the credentials, it flags the connection to be reset. When you access the connection for the first time after that, it will recreate the connection.

```
private static bool resetConnection;

private static string authKey;
private static string proxyUrl;

public static string AuthKey
{
    get => authKey;
    set
    {
       authKey = value;
       resetConnection = true;
    }
}

public static string ProxyUrl
{
    get => proxyUrl;
    set
    {
       proxyUrl = value;
       resetConnection = true;
    }
}

public static MyConnection HelperInstance
{
    get
    {
        if(resetConnection == null)
        {
            instance = new MyConnection(proxyUrl, authKey);
            resetConnection = false;
        }

        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MyConnection(proxyUrl, authKey);
            resetConnection = false;
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a locker to make the accessor thread safe

Comment: You could, but since that isn't the problem at hand here, I'd rather not put too much distraction in.